# How to get variable from header in multi query?

Tags: php, sql, variables, mysqli

i already had forms where I got the variable from the header but the forms have always been pdo and always one single query. This form is connected via mysqli and I just can't figure out how to get a variable.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost:3307", "root", "root", "test");
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
    die ("Connection failed".$mysqli->connect_error);

$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = ?;";
$query .= "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE id = ?;";

if($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do{
        $result = $mysqli->store_result();

        $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();
        echo"<table border ='1'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($finfo as $f) {
            echo "<th>".$f->name."</th>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach($row as $v) {
                echo "<td>".$v."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    } while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
}
?>
```

So the column "id" in both tables is the PK/FK and I want to retrieve information where id = ?.
How do I get the ? variable from the header and pass it on?

I feel like in my past tries I got the variable successfully with this code

```
 $id=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: Record ID not found.');
```

[...]

```
  $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
  $statement->bindParam(1, $id);
  $statement->execute();
```

but didn't echo it correctly.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well you would have to bind a value to the parameter i.e. the `?`

Comment: Also, the `mysqli_` extension is [Documented like all others in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thank you, I think I just have problems finding out where exactly to put it in the code (I am a beginner). But maybe a further look in the manual will help, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Actually I didnt think that you could do multi_query with prepared statements.

Comment: Oh okay... Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You can't use `multi_query`. You need to execute both statements separately